# How to get back the initial args used to start a DynamicSupervisor child?

Tags: elixir

I have a number of named children of a `DynamicSupervisor`. Each child process corresponds to a real-world IOT device my application controls.

Sometimes, the configuration of the real-world device changes (for instance, its maximum operating parameters). When such a change occurs, I need to terminate the supervised process and start a new one (under the same name) with the new configuration parameters.

I know `DynamicSupervisor` stores the initial arguments used to launch the process (there's no other way to support restarting processes), but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get at it.

Answer (score 1):

The process itself cannot get access to whatever does not belong to it, and the arguments are sure don’t.

Instead, you should store the arguments you need in the state of the process and implement access to this part of the state yourself.

Basically, in [`init/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:init/1) callback of *your* children process, where you do receive them, you return back the tuple `{:ok, %{arguments: init_arg, ...}}` and kinda

```elixir
@impl GenServer
def handle_call(:state, _from, state),
  do: {:ok, state, state}
```

Then you can `GenServer.call(child_pid_or_name, :state)`

Comment: I checked the internal state of the dynamic supervisor, and in the `:children` field(?) there are a bunch of `pid => child_spec`. I know the state belongs to the internal loop function, not the process itself, but why `:observer` can get it?

Comment: :observer is a debug tool, plus it gets children specs, not the states of children, afair.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use a [Registry](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Registry.html) for this, in the registry you can register all your children processes and the registry can keep all the names of your process, and also if you try to register a process with the same name (pid) the Registry will tell you that is already registered but that just if you configured your Registry to have unique keys.

And when you register the process you pass a value to the Registry, that could be your arguments, so the Registry can keep the initial arguments.

This is an example of a Dynamic Supervisor + Registry: https://blog.appsignal.com/2019/08/13/elixir-alchemy-multiplayer-go-with-registry-pubsub-and-dynamic-supervisors.html